# Show information based on date selected

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'd like to make a little page that shows different details based on a date range chosen.
For example, I'd like to have three or four date ranges (eg: from 1 January 2013 - today, from 1 July 2012 - 31 December 2012 and from 1 January 2012 - 30 June 2012) and if the date range chosen by the user with the date picker falls into one of those brackets, the information displayed (in a div) will change.

Eg:
1. Enter the date you joined our club: [date picker] 
2. Div container showing information based on the selection made in the date picker

---

Can anyone give me some help for how this is done? 
Thanks

Comment: show us what you tried and what didn't work, then we can sure help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try (jQuery and jQuery ui)

```
    <input id='dp1' />
    <div id="div1" style='display:none' > Some info for range date 1</div>
    <div id="div2" style='display:none'> Some info for range date 2</div>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dp1").datepicker().on('change', function(){
         var date =  $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        // months are based 0
        if (date >=  new Date(2013,0,1) && date <= new Date(2013,1,28) ){
            $("#div2").hide();
            $("#div1").show();
        }
        else if (date >= new Date(2013,2,1) && date <= new Date(2013,3,15)){
            $("#div2").show();
            $("#div1").hide();
        }


    });;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCUZX/5/)

Comment: far too kind ;-) I think you just did his homework, but I may be wrong on that